# OnClick multiple conditions

Tags: delphi, if-statement, onclick, delphi-7

```
 procedure TForm1.Panel3Click(Sender: TObject);

 begin

  if item.caption='1' then
    begin
       form2.WebBrowser1.Navigate('link1');
       form2.Caption:='1';
       form2.Show;
    end;
  if item.caption='2' then
    begin
       form2.WebBrowser1.Navigate('link2');
       form2.Caption:='2';
       form2.Show;
    end;
 end.
```

what im trying to do is on Onclick event check item's caption and then browse a specefic link, this doesnt work and i tried the switch method which doesnt work too(sorry for my bad english), any suggestions on how can i make it work ?

Comment: What is item? How doesn't it work? What's the switch method? How doesn't it work?

Comment: Your code works just fine, although it is sub optimal

Comment: @SertacAkyuz it's a menu item named groupe so it's groupe.caption, for the swtich statement it's also called the 'case' statement

Comment: @Ferhat: If you are clicking on menu items, then why is your `OnClick` handler named `Panel3Click`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau  On Panel3Click it checks item's caption and do specefic instructions

Comment: @Ferhat: that did not answer my question, or anyone else's, for that matter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OnMenuItemClick is another procedure, my main problem is that OnPanel3Click is supposed to get item's caption which in this case is a MainMenuItem, compare it with a given value and do specefic instructions, but it doesnt using the code above.

Comment: @Ferhat: Then why is the code you showed inside of `Panel3Click` at all?  Sounds like it should be inside of `OnMenuItemClick` instead.  What is `Panel3` for exactly?

Comment: @Ferhat What debugging have you made? Have you checked the value of `Item.caption` before it is being compared in the if statement? You can do this but putting a breakpoint on the `if ...` line and then hower over `Item.Caption ` with your mouse once program has paused hitting that breakpoint. Somehow I suspect that `Item` might not be the `Item` you expect it to be. Or perhaps your `Item.Caption` stores some additional characters like & which are used for menu hotkeys (those underlined letters in menues that allow you to simulate click on specific menu when pressing the underlined letter).

Comment: @RemyLebeau panel3 is simply a panel and it has an onclick event

Comment: @SilverWarior i discoverded that Item.Caption isnt actually the value shown, perhaps it stores some additional characters as you said.

Comment: That is why it is bad idea of using caption in the first place. What would be best is to actually make a decendat class of the item class to add aditional field to it that will store the URL or any other needed data. This way you won't need to have any if or case staments but simply fread that data from the item object. Ofcourse changing the time clas would also require chaning of the component that stores those itmes so that it will use your derived class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly "doesnt work" for you?  You need to be more specific.  There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown, provided that `item` has been declared and assigned beforehand (and `end.` is really `end;`).

I suspect that you want `item` to be the object that was clicked, is that right?  If so, then you simply need to assign this `OnClick` handle to the relevant objects and then type-cast the `Sender` parameter accordingly, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.PanelClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  item: TPanel;
begin
  item := Sender as TPanel; // or TMenuItem, or whatever you are using...
  if item.Caption = '1' then
  begin
    Form2.WebBrowser1.Navigate('link1');
    Form2.Caption := '1';
    Form2.Show;
  end
  else if item.Caption = '2' then
  begin
    Form2.WebBrowser1.Navigate('link2');
    Form2.Caption := '2';
    Form2.Show;
  end;
end;
```

Personally, I would not use the `Caption` to make decisions.  I would do something more like this instead:

```
const
  Links: array[1..2] of string = (
    'link1',
    'link2'
    // and so on...
  );

procedure TForm1.PanelClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  item: TPanel;
begin
  item := Sender as TPanel; // or whatever...
  Form2.WebBrowser1.Navigate(Links[item.Tag]);
  Form2.Caption := item.Caption;
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

Where the object with `Caption='1'` has `Tag=1` assigned, and the object with `Caption='2'` has `Tag=2` assigned, and so on.

In the chance that you actually only have 1 object whose `Caption` you change dynamically based on other conditions, then this approach still works, simply update the `Tag` accordingly whenever you update the `Caption`.

Comment: the problem is even when item.caption='1' or '2' it doesnt do anything.       item is a MainMenu item

Comment: "doesn't do anything" does not tell us the real problem you are having. Is `item` assigned before `OnClick` is called?  Did you verify that `OnClick` is even being called at all?

Comment: @Ferhat If `Item`is Mainmenu item, did you assign an `OnClick` handler for it (or them)? Hint: Object Inspector, Events, OnClick.

Comment: @TomBrunberg You can also do double click on MenuItem in MainMenu or PopupMenu designer.